# How to group by values but keep data structure?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataset which contains a list of units (stores) selling a system with sales and units for every week. I have grouped them into a test and control group as a new column.

What I want to do now is to use these new groups in the dataset, as I want to plot them against each other for all the weeks.

My best shot at this so far have been this:
  `df_group = df.groupby('Group')['Sales'].sum()`
However, that just sums them all up not per week.

```
   Unit  Year  Week System_Type   Sales  Units_Sold
0  6111  2019     1  Component2  109578        3139
1  6111  2019     1  Component1   20792         639
2  6111  2019     2  Component2  115363        3425
3  6111  2019     2  Component1   25261         796
4  6111  2019     3  Component2  114913        3352

df['Group'] = np.where(((df['Unit'] == 6111) | (df['Unit'] == 6112) | (df['Unit'] == 6121)), 'control', 'test')
df.head()
    Unit    Year    Week    System_Type Sales   Units_Sold  Group
0   6111    2019    1   Component2  109578  3139    control
1   6111    2019    1   Component1  20792   639 control
2   6111    2019    2   Component2  115363  3425    control
3   6111    2019    2   Component1  25261   796 control
4   6111    2019    3   Component2  114913  3352    control

time = df.Week.unique()

df_cat = df[df.System_Type == 'Component1']
```

I have been looking at this for some time without being able to google my way to a correct solution. I'm thinking maybe to use the "time" variable as new index?

Any help much appreciated!

Comment: if you want to groupby and sum and keep the same index then use transform, like the following: `df.groupby('Week')['Sales'].transform('sum')`

Comment: So `df_group = df.groupby(['Week','Group')['Sales'].sum()`

Comment: @Wen-Ben missing a `]`

Comment: Thanks, worked perfectly!

Answer (score 0):

let's play:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_table('c:/4/AAA.txt', sep=',')
df.head(10)

df.groupby(['Week','Sales']).sum().sort_values('Sales')
df[(df['Sales']>30000)&(df['Year']==2019)].sort_values('Sales')
df[df['System_Type']=='Component2'].groupby('Sales').filter(lambda x: len(x)<2500).groupby('Sales').size().to_frame('size').sort_values('size')
```